# Raphael JS use SVG fill pattern

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I can use fill patterns for SVG graphics.
But they don't seem to work with raphael.js.

When I try referencing a fill pattern, nothing happens.

```
fill_circle.attr("fill": "url(#diagonalHatch)");
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dfg7Lktc/

1. The circle on the top is a regular SVG filled with a #diagonalHatch fill pattern I created
2. The left circle is made with raphael and filled yellow, working fine
3. The right circle is made with raphael too and filled with the #diagonalHatch fill pattern, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to use fill patterns with raphael? Or do they only work with "real" SVG objects?

Did I make any mistake?

Comment: Raph seems to do something funky with that url. If there isn't a better answer (there's a few other solutions on SO, but not quite sure if they apply), this should work... fill_circle.node.setAttributeNS(null,"fill",'url(#diagonalHatch)');

Comment: You made my day, thank you so much!
(I just found out about SNAP.svg, the successor of Raphael, but good to know anyway :D)

Answer (score 0):

Raphael as far as I know, does not support this. However, Snap.svg, which was created by the same guy, does.